# porque un combo dependiente no me agarra el primer valor

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un proyecto en php donde tengo que registrar a un alumno en una sección de un curso, tengo un primer combobox donde muestro los cursos que hay disponibles y luego un segundo combobox que dependiendo del curso que seleccione aparezca las secciones que hay disponible para ese curso. el primer combobox lo tengo de esta forma

```
 <?php $query = "SELECT id_curso, nombre_curso, estatus FROM curso WHERE estatus='disponible' ";
                            $resultado=$mysqli->query($query); ?>

                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label style="margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 25px" for="cbx_curso" class="col-md-2 control-label">Taller o Curso:<span class="asterisco">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-3 " style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; margin-left: -80px; ">
                          <select name="cbx_curso" id="cbx_curso" class="form-control">
                                            <option value="0" style="">Seleccionar Curso</option>

                    <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_curso']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_curso']; ?></option>

                    <?php } ?>
                          </select>

                        </div>
                      </div>
```

el segundo combobox dependiente sale de acá

```
    $id_curso = $_POST['id_curso'];

    $queryS = "SELECT id_seccion, descripcion FROM seccion WHERE curso_id_curso = '$id_curso'";
    $resultadoS = $mysqli->query($queryS);



    $html= "<option value='0'>Elija una opción</option>";


    while($rowS = $resultadoS->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $html.= "<option value='".$rowS['id_seccion']."'>".$rowS['descripcion']."</option>";


    }



    echo $html;
?>
```

lo hago funcionar con este script

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_curso").change(function () {



                    $("#cbx_curso option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_curso = $(this).val();
                        $.post("../includes/getSeccion.php", { id_curso: id_curso }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_seccion").html(data);
                        });


                    });
                })
            });

</script>
```

pero me esta pasando que cuando voy hacer la inscripción y selecciono el primer curso me toma el segundo curso. si selecciono el segundo me toma el tercero y así sucesivamente.
En el caso cuando tengo un curso con mas de dos secciones por ejemplo cuatro secciones y selecciono la tercera seccion siempre se selecciona es la segunda seccion de ese combobox indistintamente asi seleccione la cuarta o si hay una quinta, siempre se guarda en la base de datos es la segunda seccion. a quien pueda ayudarme se lo agradeceria

Comment: ¿Y el HTML de `cbx_seccion` dónde está? ¿Qué imprime `console.log(data);` en tu petición Ajax? ¿Cómo es el código de `getSeccion.php`?

Comment: en el html de getseccion tengo esto $id_curso = $_POST['id_curso'];
 
 $queryS = "SELECT id_seccion, descripcion FROM seccion WHERE curso_id_curso = '$id_curso'";
 $resultadoS = $mysqli->query($queryS);
 
 

 $html= "<option value='0'>Elija una opción</option>";

 
 while($rowS = $resultadoS->fetch_assoc())
 {

Comment: $html.= "<option value='".$rowS['id_seccion']."'>".$rowS['descripcion']."</option>";
  

 }


 
 echo $html;